# Macromedia FreeHand-- Bevel & Emboss

Tags: vector, adobe-freehand

I've just begun using Macromedia FreeHand (version before it became Adobe Freehand) that we had laying around. And I want to do this same thing--namely, invert a shadow.

In FreeHand there are two effects called "Bevel" and "Emboss". They both are pretty similar to each other. But, I can't seem to get that far because the shape I bring in from ArcMap is a river polygon. In ArcMap it's a filled in polygon, but when I import the EMF file to FreeHand it becomes a polyline image. This is where I'm having problems... Does anyone know how to fill the shape to look like it did as a polgon (see before/after images)?

BEFORE:
[image]

AFTER:
[image]

Zoomed in....

[image]

Comment: Bit off topic but I'm really curious - what kind of computer are you using that is even able to run MM at this point?

Comment: I wish I had a working copy of Macromedia Freehand to help you, but alas no. The last computer I had that it worked on died some years ago.  Have you thought about getting Adobe Illustrator, or if you have no cash to splash, perhaps Inkscape?  Both have emboss/bevel type effects.

Comment: It kind of looks like you just need to switch the fill and stroke.  It is hard to tell without seeing the construction of the paths specifically (in addition to the 15-20 year old software in use).

Comment: @Ryan: Dell Windows 7

Comment: @Billy:  I've considered Adobe, but was going over alternatives first. There are a bunch of open source alternatives, which I'm looking into. Search "Alternatives to Adobe Illustrator" for a discussion on them, fyi..

Comment: @Scott: Sorry, I don't really know what I'm doing in Freehand. When I try to fill the color doesn't stay between the lines?
I have a zoomed in image but can't seem to post it here?

Comment: It's been too long for me to give specifics where Freehand is concerned... You can add a link to a third image.. someone will make it inline for you. There's merely a limit to teh number of images for new users. Once you have more reputation, that limit will vanish.

Comment: http://www.willcogis.org/website2014/gis/Data/Rivers2.jpg
Here's a link to a zoomed in area of the river. Basically, I'm trying to fill between the lines and when I use the pointer to select a couple line sections, select Add Fill and then select the color it fills way outside the lines?

Comment: Oh boy... you've got a bunch of unconnected paths.  Quite honestly it would be easier to use the pen tool and redraw everything manually than to try and correct that artwork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From you enlarged image what is happening is that the segments aren’t closed. So it is force closing them by using the first and last points (hence the straight line going across). This is a bit fiddly but you need to select each adjoining segment along the river then use modify/join (or for quicker way drag around the area then try joining (you may need to experiment with this to get the correct joins). Basically what you want is to get one complete closed segment going along the whole river (ie along one side then down the other side so that the end point and the start point are the same). 
Once done you then need to sort out the islands. To do this you can select all then do command/join (but this must be done at the end – ie join all segments up first). To check if a segment is closed use command/object.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have some work to do, I see. I've since moved on to try another graphic application, Inkscape. But, the river looks the same there too. So, I'm assuming it's a matter of connecting all the nodes to close the paths in Inkscape too.

Comment: OK, good luck. It might be worth seeing what happens in FH if you select everything (command + A  ,on a mac) then join (command +J). It might be that just a bit of tidying up is then needed.  If an error message comes up saying too many points then just go to modify/alter path/simplify. Sorry not been able to post back until today.